Next.js 15.1.2 with react-leaflet 5.0.0-rc.1: Component won't load. Tried StrictMode false, SSR off, dynamic import, 'use client', leaflet.css
I've observed that the leaflet component fails to load whenever I include the Leaflet CSS file, regardless of what I try. I’ve also noticed a strange behavior where the map loads when I remove the leaflet.css import from my Leaflet.tsx file, but it appears completely scattered and unorganized.
It seems that the absence of the CSS affects the map’s proper rendering, causing layout issues. However, including the CSS prevents the component from loading entirely and I am faced with a blank component, which is equally problematic.
Here is my package.json
Leaflet.tsx
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import {
    MapContainer,
    TileLayer,
    Marker,
    Popup,
    useMapEvents,
} from 'react-leaflet';
import { useState } from 'react';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css';
const Leaflet = () => {
    function LocationMarker() {
        const [position, setPosition] = useState<L.LatLng | null>(null);
        const map = useMapEvents({
            click() {
                map.locate();
            },
            locationfound(e) {
                setPosition(e.latlng);
                map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
            },
        });
        return position === null ? null : (
            <Marker position={position}>
                <Popup>You are here</Popup>
            </Marker>
        );
    }
    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={[51.505, -0.09]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            <LocationMarker />
        </MapContainer>
    );
};
export default Leaflet;


Dynamic import into my component
    const LeafletMap = useMemo(
        () =>
            dynamic(() => import('@/components/Leaflet'), {
                loading: () => <p>A map is loading</p>,
                ssr: false,
            }),
        [],
    );

My development screen
Leaflet when css import is removed
